# Pokemon Go On My iPod 5th Gen

Tags: pokemon-go

I've just downloaded Pokemon GO on my iPod 5 and it keeps telling me in the app "GPS signal not found." Does this mean that I can't play the game without the wi-fi at my house? Also I'm pretty sure that my iPod 5 doesn't have a GPS system built into it so does that mean I can't play Pokemon GO?

Because my iPod doesn't have mobile data does that mean I can't play it outside like I am supposed to?

Answer (score 3):

If your device does not have a GPS system you will not be able to play Pokemon Go